# How to change MKAnnotation Color using Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, annotations

I have `MKAnnotations` set up on a map, but I would like to change the color of the annotations for different scenario's. Is there a way to change the color of the annotation?

Here is my code below, how would I implement the color change?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    currentLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: MapViewLocationManager.location)
    //annotationQuery.whereKey("Location", nearGeoPoint: currentLoc, withinMiles: 10)
    annotationQuery.whereKeyExists("Location")
    annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (points, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successful query for annotations")
            // Do something with the found objects

            let myPosts = points as! [PFObject]

            for post in myPosts {
                let point = post["Location"] as! PFGeoPoint
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)
                annotation.title = post["title"] as! String!
                annotation.subtitle = post["username"] as! String!


                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you implement any delegate methods, make sure the map view's delegate outlet in the storyboard is connected to the view controller otherwise your delegate methods will not get called.

Answer (score 7):

You can use custom images for annotation view or use predefined `MKPinAnnotationView` with `pinColor`. But pinColors limited to Red, Green and Purple.

Some example:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    var custom_image: Bool = true
    var color: MKPinAnnotationColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Purple
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    let annotation = Annotation.new()
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let annotation2 = Annotation.new()
    annotation2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 1.0)
    annotation2.custom_image = false
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation2)

    let annotation3 = Annotation.new()
    annotation3.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 1.0, longitude:  0.0)
    annotation3.custom_image = false
    annotation3.color = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation3)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        if let anAnnotation = annotation as? Annotation {
            if anAnnotation.custom_image {
                let reuseId = "custom_image"
                anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                anView.image = UIImage(named:"custom_image")
            }
            else {
                let reuseId = "pin"
                let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                pinView.pinColor = anAnnotation.color
                anView = pinView
            }
        }
        anView.canShowCallout = false
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}
}
```

**Update:**
Set delegate for mapView in viewDidLoad

Comment: I tried out some of the methods below but the pencolor still won't change. I have posted my current code above in the original post.

Comment: Post the `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!` method also

Comment: how do I properly implement the viewForAnnotation method within my code posted above? It doesn't want to turn the pin color green or purple.

Comment: I've edited my post above. Add `self.mapView.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set it in the [viewForAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:viewForAnnotation:) method.
[In this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial) is quite well explained how doing it.